# Add item into device Calendar by URL on page

Tags: web, calendar, icalendar, vcf-vcard

We would like to let a user with mobile device (Notebook/Tablet/Smartphone) add an event to his Calendar by just hitting a button/link/url from our MOBILE WEBSITE.

How can we provide this? (We read that this is not possible with an Stock Android Google calendar).

Answer (score 0):

the button should point to a icalendar file describing the event (see rfc5545) when downloaded the client will then add the event to the local calendar.